# Немного запутался с вложенными циклами

Tags: циклы, c++

map[0][j] - сюда я пытаюсь вывести каждую цифру в 1й строчке в каждый отдельный столбик цифры должны выводиться от нуля до 9, но почему то не получается.. если нужно могу скинуть полный исходный код. Если что не так сделал прошу извинить, это мой первый вопрос

```
for(int v = 0; v < 10; v++)
{
    for(int j = 2; j < 12; j++)
    {
        map[0][j] = v;
    }

}
```

Comment: выводились не те символы потому что num было равно 0, поэтому выводились не понятные символы, на будущее цифры начинают выводиться с 48, а буквы с 65. спасибо всем

Answer (score 5):

Cудя по всему, после выполнения вашего кода map[0][j] будет содержать в себе сплошные девятки. 
Возможно, я не очень понял, что вы хотите, но, думаю, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
int num = 0;
for(int j = 2; j < 12; j++)
    map[0][j] = num++;
```

Comment: ☺☻♥♦♣     <- вместо цифр от 0 до 9, выводятся эти символы..

Comment: @ArturShvaiberov: а как вы выводите? подумайте над тем, как вывести число 0x09.

Comment: >вместо цифр от 0 до 9, выводятся эти символы
 
простите, любезный, а вы еще хотите, чтоб за вас и вывод цифр написали? Уж сделайте хоть что-нибудь сами что ли